# Curl not working on OS X

Tags: macos, curl

I recently upgraded XCode and while I'm not sure if that caused the problem, I can't curl out of my computer anymore.  This seems to break rvm and homebrew but git still works.  I upgraded curl and the problem still exists so I'm not sure it's actually a curl issue but not really sure how to debug from here.

wget also just hangs

Here is the verbose output from curl:

```
$ curl http://www.google.com -v
* About to connect() to www.google.com port 80 (#0)
*   Trying 74.125.227.178...
```

ssh works fine!

Any ideas on how to debug?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?